# Deploying Sanity Studio to AWS Amplify as a subdomain

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, sanity

I have a next project in which I have sanity initialized.

so my project structure looks like this,

```
--myXprojectFolder
----sanity_myXprojectFolder
```

In my local I can cd into `sanity_myXprojectFolder` and run `sanity start` to run dashboard but, in Amplify I dont know how to run this sub directory as a subdomain.

What I want to achieve is, when I go to admin.mydomain.com to run this sub directory.

What I tried is, In git i have created a branch called `admin` then I removed the parent project and moved the `sanity_myXprojectFolder` contents to the parent directory so my admin branch only has sanity contents. But this did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with the same issue only to discover a very simple fix.

You need to adapt Amplify's build settings (`amplify.yaml`) to use the `/dist/` directory as its base directory like so:

```
frontend:
...
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: /dist/
...
```

Here is my full `amplify.yaml` for reference:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: /dist/
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```